# How to consume web service soap with a certificate that requires a password?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, pem, zeep

I am trying to consume a web service in python, previously I have consumed it without difficulties in java.

To consume the soap web service I have a certificate with .keystore extension.

To consume this service in python I use the python request and zeep packages, for which I converted the .keystore into .pem with keytool.

I could not remove the password to the certificate, so the .pem needs a password.

This is what I am doing:

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  
import requests

url = 'https://10.15.1.76:8443/ws/MyService?wsdl'
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("user","password")

transport = Transport(session=session)  
client = Client(url,transport=transport)
```

But I do not know how to add the certificate with the password.
I know that python3.x has a class for ssl, something like this:

```
from ssl import SSLContext

context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_cert_chain('my.pem', keyfile=None, password='password_pem')
```

I would appreciate any information. Thank you.